# Proving $\frac{x+1}{y+1}$ is equal to or less than $\frac{x-1}{y-1}$

Tags: inequality

I know that $\frac{x+1}{y+1}$ is equal to (when $x = y$) or less than $\frac{x-1}{y-1}$. Suppose we cross multiply, then

1. $xy - x+ y -1$ is less than or equal to $xy + x - y -1$
   So,
2. $y- x$ is less than or equal to $x- y$.
   But when $y$ is greater than $x$ then the inequality is wrong.
   Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{x+1}{y+1}\leq\frac{x-1}{y-1}$ ?

Comment: @Cornman yes sir. sorry I dont know MathJax.

Comment: $x+\frac{1}{y}+1$ or $x+\frac{1}{y+1}$ or $\frac{x+1}{y+1}$?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit last one. (x+1)/(y+1) sorry

Comment: It is no problem when you are not familiar with MathJax or LaTex, but please use brackets. Is this the original question?

Comment: @Cornman yes sir thank you and sorry.

Comment: You need some restrictions on $x$ and $y$, because when you change the sign of both you exchange the fractions. $(-x+1)/(-y+1)=(x-1)/(y-1)$ and $(-x-1)/(-y-1)=(x+1)/(y+1)$

Comment: Be careful with cross-multiplication in inequalities. The underlying principle in that process is an equivalence principle that however only works if the sign of the quantity you use for multiplication is known and fixed! @Ram Keswani

Answer (score 5):

You have
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{x+1}{y+1}-\frac{x-1}{y-1}=
\frac{(xy+y-x-1)-(xy+x-y-1)}{(y^2-1)}=
\frac{2(y-x)}{(y^2-1)}
$$
Then
$$
f(x,y)\begin{cases}
>0 & \text{if $y>x$ and $|y|>1$} \\[4px]
>0 & \text{if $y<x$ and $|y|<1$} \\[4px]
<0 & \text{if $y>x$ and $|y|<1$} \\[4px]
<0 & \text{if $y<x$ and $|y|>1$}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $ 1 \leq y \leq x $ then $ y-x \leq x-y $. Now add $xy-1$ to both sides and factorise to get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace{xy+y-x-1}_{(x+1)(y-1)} \leq \underbrace{xy+x-y-1}_{ (x-1)(y+1)} \\
\frac{x+1}{y+1} \leq \frac{x-1}{y-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}